# Como integrar post de um site para outros no WordPress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress

Comecei a utilizar o Multisite do WordPress.. Estou com dificuldade em chamar alguns posts de um determinado site para outro. Como posso fazer isso dentro do Multisite?

Pesquisando, achei alguns codigos para colocar no `functions.php` mas não funcionaram...

Comment: É exatamente como diz o Eitch. Aqui tem [um exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23376788/1287812) fazendo algo parecido com um shortcode. Se pesquisar nas minhas respostas no [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:12615+[multisite]) e [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1287812+%5Bwordpress%5D+multisite) vai encontrar bastante código útil. Boa sorte! . . . PS: nunca use nada no `functions.php` para trabalhar com Multisite, é plugin ou Must use plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Há algumas maneiras de fazer isso que você está querendo. A maneira mais simples (que serve para muitos casos) é utilizar o mecanismo de RSS para replicar de um site para outro.

Por exemplo, você quer "exportar" a categoria *compartilhados* do seu site, primeiro você pega a URL do RSS desta categoria, que seria algo como:

```
http://seusite/categoria/compartilhados/rss
```

E então usa essa URL em um Plugin de sindicância de RSS. Esse tipo de plugin lê um RSS e posta o seu conteúdo em forma de posts dentro do blog. Um desses plugins é o FeedWordPress, disponível em https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/.

Outra maneira é utilizar a função *[switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)* para alternar entre blogs dentro de uma instalação MultiSite. Ao usar essa função, todo o código depois dela passa a ser executado em um outro blog. Por exemplo, no meio da sua home do blog *um* você pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php
// muda para o blog de ID 2
switch_to_blog(2);

// prepara uma nova consulta com os 5 ultimos posts
wp_reset_query();
query_posts('showposts=5');

// usa o loop para mostrar os posts
if ( have_posts() ) :
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
  endwhile;
endif;

// importante: volta para o blog anterior
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

Dessa forma você pode fazer todo tipo de consulta de itens dentro de um blog, para mostrar em outro blog da forma que quiser.

Fontes, em inglês, sobre o assunto:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/get-posts-from-sites-in-multisite
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89113/restore-current-blog-vs-switch-to-blog
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-query-posts-in-multisite-network

Comment: Pô, você cita uns posts importantes lá no WPSE, mas tá usando [***`query_posts`***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)?¿ :)

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo... :)